# MySQL query sub query or grouping

Tags: mysql, subquery

Each modx_site_content record may have several records in modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.

I need to retrieve both modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.value where the tvv.tmplvarid = 3 AND the tvv.tmplvarid = 1. where tvv.tmplvarid is a future date, I need to return the tvv.value of tvv.tmplvarid 3 which is a comma separated list of tags.

This query does not return the values I need & I'm not sure how to get just what I want.

```
SELECT sc.id, sc.pagetitle, tvv.value, tvv.tmplvarid, tvv.id, tvv.value
FROM modx_site_content sc
left join modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues tvv on tvv.contentid = sc.id
where published = '1' 
and (tvv.tmplvarid = '3' and tvv.value >= curdate())
order by sc.id;
```

basically in the end I need to return only the list of tags (tvv.tmplvarid = 3) where the other associated record (tvv.tmplvarid = 1) is a date in the future.

Any thoughts, can this be done with grouping instead? I don't actually need anything from the modx_site_content table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to return the tags both rows in the `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues` table that has `tmplvarid` of 1 and 3 both related to the same `modx_site_content`, but only when the  `tmplvarid` 3 row has a datetime field in the future?

I would do two separate joins to the modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues tabe:

```
SELECT tOne.value, tThree.value
FROM modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues tOne
INNER JOIN modx_site_content c ON tOne.contentid = c.id
INNER JOIN modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues tThree ON tThree.contentid = c.id
WHERE c.published = 1
AND tOne.tmplvarid = 1 
AND tThree.tmplvarid = 3 AND tThree.date > NOW()
```

*SQL Fiddle:* http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4031/2

Comment: I see where you are going with that, but it returns values from before 'now' as well.

Comment: SQL query was slightly wrong (just updated the sql fiddle), it has a row with a date in the past that doesn't get returned.

Comment: that works if you add AS date after tThree.value or change the AND tThree.date to tThree.value. Yours is faster by .003s [at least in my testing] so cheers, both work, but yours is more efficient.

Comment: some reason, I have to wait a day to give u the bounty .... hopefully I remember ;)

Comment: Ah great - glad it works. He he, 0.003 seconds - not a huge improvement, but better than nothing! Did you put `SQL_NO_CACHE` just after the `SELECT` keyword when you benchmarked? Otherwise the query cache will kick in and not give you (potentially) unrealistic timings, depending on your servers query profile. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

Comment: no I did not - not something I had considered! thanks, will have to file that one away for future reference. .... when I did, both queries ran at 0.036 - 0.039s ... no appreciable difference. Then again, the data set is not very large at all, a few hundred records at best.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Amazing what you can do if you just read the docs ;)

```
select tv.contentid, tv.value as eventdate, sc.id, sc.pagetitle, tvv.value from 
(   
 select * from modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues cv 
 where cv.tmplvarid = 3
 and cv.value >= curdate() 
) as tv  
left join modx_site_content sc on sc.id = tv.contentid
left join modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues tvv on tvv.contentid = sc.id
where (tvv.tmplvarid = 1)
order by value asc
```

Comment: I would use two joins rather than a sub select - should be faster. I've put an example in my answer.